# Issues with Caching on OkHttpClient 2.0

Tags: android, http-caching, okhttp

I have an issue with caching using OkHttpClient 2.0. It seems that the Response is ignoring the Cache-Control header completely. This is how I am setting up the client and the cache.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
cache = new Cache(new File(Session.getInstance().getContext().getCacheDir(),"http"), 10 * 1024 * 1024); 
client.setCache(cache);
client.setCookieHandler(CookieHandler.getDefault());
client.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
client.setReadTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I believe that the cache directory is created correctly. This is what I see in journal in the /cache/http directory of my application.

```
libcore.io.DiskLruCache
1
201105
2
```

This is how I am creating the Request.

```
Request mRequest =  new Request.Builder().url(mUrl).get().build();
```

Getting the response :

```
Response response = client.newCall(mRequest).execute();
```

When using curl, the headers as as follows.

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 27 Jun 2014 19:39:40 GMT
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Cache-Control: no-transform, max-age=1800
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

The OKHttp response headers are as follows.

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Fri, 27 Jun 2014 18:58:30 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
OkHttp-Received-Millis:1403895511337
OkHttp-Selected-Protocol:http/1.1
OkHttp-Sent-Millis:1403895511140
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

The responses never get cached and the call client.getCache().getHitCount() always gives 0. Can someone please suggest what changes might be required here to make the cache work? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, the problem was all my get and post requests were using the Authorization Bearer xxxx header and http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html section 14.8 states that these requests can't be cached. The solution was to use s-maxage on the server instead of just max age according to this :

> When a shared cache (see section 13.7) receives a request
>         containing an Authorization field, it MUST NOT return the
>         corresponding response as a reply to any other request, unless one
>         of the following specific exceptions holds:
>
> If the response includes the "s-maxage" cache-control
>            directive, the cache MAY use that response in replying to a
>            subsequent request.

Answer (score 1):

Are you reading the entire response body? OkHttp won't cache unless you consume the entire response.

Comment: I am doing this : `String responseBody = response.body.string()` after executing the request, if that is what you mean by consuming the response. Also closing it : `response.body().close()`.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you solved your specific problem, but the symptom you describe has another cause.

When using the okhttp-urlconnection, caching doesn't kick in by default, unless we do this:

`connection.setUseCaches(true)`

(It should be on by default, but some library I was using was setting it to off)